# How safe is client-side HTML Sanitization?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, knockout.js, javascript-injection

I have been looking at Pagedown.js lately for the allure of using mark-down on my pages instead of ugly readonly textareas.

I am extremely cautious though as it seems easy enough to dupe the sanitized converter.  I have seen some discussion around Angular.js and it's html bindings and also heard something when Knockout.js 3.0 came out that there had been a previous unsafeness to the html binding.

It would seem all someone would need to do to disable the sanitizer in Pagedown.js for instance is something like -

```
var safeConverter = new Markdown.Converter();
// safeConverter is open to script injection

safeConverter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
// safeConverter is now safe

// Override the getSanitizingConverter pseudo-code
Markdown.getSanitizingConverter = function () {
    return Markdown.Converter;
};
```

and they could open a site up to script injection.  Is that not true?

**Edit**

Then why would libraries like that package a sanitizer to use client-side?  Sure they say don't render unsanitized html but the next line says use Markdown.Sanitizer..

How is Angular not open to it with the sanitizer service or is that just a farce as well?

Comment: It's completely true. *Nothing* client-side is safe.

Comment: It seems like more answerers answer as if this question was about client-side validation. Sanitization is something totally different (in fact it takes place on the exact opposite side of the spectrum: (client-side) validation happens before users send data out, (client-side) sanitization happens after users receive data from the server). Sanitizaton **does** make you app safer, but only in tandem with other meassures/practices.

Comment: It is a very important step in the right direction, should definitely be part of your app. It doesn't magically solve all of your problems though. It is a useful tool and should be used nd treated accordingly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe there is a little misunderstanding about the purpose and nature of such "sanitizers".

The purpose of a sanitizer (e.g. Angular's `ngSanitize`) is **not** to prevent "bad" data from being sent to the server-side. It is rather the other way around: A sanitizer is there to **protect** the non-malicious user from malicious data (being either a result of a security hole on the server side (yeah, no setup is perfect) or being fetched from other sources (ones that you are not in control of)).

Of course, being a client-side feature, a sanitizer could be bypassed, but (since the sanitizer is there to protect the user (not the server)) bypassing it would only leave the bypasser unprotected (which you can't do anything about, nor shouldn't you care - it's their choice).

Furthermore, sanitizers (can) have another (potentially more important) role: A sanitizer is a tool that helps the developer to better organize their code in a way that it is more easily testable for certain kinds of vulnerabilities (e.g. XSS attacks) and even helps in the actual code auditing for such kind of security holes.

In my opinion, the **[Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce)** summarize the concept pretty neatly:

> Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) is a mode in which AngularJS requires bindings in certain contexts to result in a value that is marked as safe to use for that context.
>   [...]
>   SCE assists in writing code in way that (a) **is secure by default** and (b) makes **auditing** for security vulnerabilities such as XSS, clickjacking, etc. **a lot easier**.
>
> [...]
>   In a more realistic example, one may be rendering user comments, blog articles, etc. via bindings. (HTML is just one example of a context where rendering user controlled input creates security vulnerabilities.)
>
> For the case of HTML, you might use a library, either on the client side, or on the server side, to sanitize unsafe HTML before binding to the value and rendering it in the document.
>
> How would you ensure that every place that used these types of bindings was bound to a value that was sanitized by your library (or returned as safe for rendering by your server?) How can you ensure that you didn't accidentally **delete the line that sanitized** the value, or **renamed some properties/fields** and forgot to update the binding to the sanitized value?
>
> To be secure by default, you want to ensure that any such bindings are disallowed unless you can determine that **something explicitly says it's safe** to use a value for binding in that context. You can then **audit your code** (a simple grep would do) to ensure that this is only done for those values that you can easily tell are safe - because they were received from your server, sanitized by your library, etc. You can **organize your codebase to help with this** - perhaps allowing only the files in a specific directory to do this. Ensuring that the internal API exposed by that code doesn't markup arbitrary values as safe then becomes **a more manageable task**.

<sub>**Note 1:** Emphasis is mine.

**Note 2:** Sorry for the lengthy quote, but I consider this to be a very improtant (as much as sensitive) matter and one that is too often misunderstood.</sub>

Comment: I know the other answer was higher voted but I believe that was just because how quickly it was answered - I believe your answer better addresses what the purpose of the client-side sanitizers are for and how they protect the server / user and what the risk of exposure is if they are bypassed.

Answer (score 8):

You can't sanitize client side. Anyone could always turn off JavaScript or change the values and submit them to your server.

The server *needs* to double check that. Client side in my mind is really just a usability feature. So they know as they type whether they are wrong or right.

*In response to the edit:*

Most of them are convenience or provide functionality. For example [unobtrusive validation](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html) will make my text boxes red if they put in an invalid number. That is nice, and I didn't need to post and check and then change the text box border blablablabla...

But when they do post I still need to validate their data. I usually keep that in a core library which could be shared across applications (web, web service, mobile app, thick client etc)

The usability validation varies platform to platform. But at the core, before any application trusts the data, it has to check it within its trust barrier. No one can change the value behind my `if` on the server, but anyone can change the value in their browser without tripping my JS.

Comment: Yeah, you can sanitize on the client side (and it's a good idea too). Sanitization !== Validation

Comment: Admiral Adama I appreciate your answer but I feel that it is the same misconception that I have / have had about sanitizers, I believe ExpertSystem's answer better addresses the question and provides better references to back it up - if you disagree please feel free to let me know and we can discuss!

Comment: I agree, I voted him up a couple days ago when I was reading his post. It is a great post. 

I latched on to the 'safe' word you used. The issue is that while it can help protect the end user, it doesn't replace sanitization and security server side. I would still suggest that this isn't a safe way to prevent XSS, relying on this library to work client side isn't safe. But it is helpful :). Thanks for the note though @PWKad

Comment: @ExpertSystem You can also NOT sanitize on the client side if Javascript is turned off.

Comment: @RobertMallow: And nor do you need to.

Comment: @PWKad I think you are right. It is mostly a semantics issue, but I see a lot of fresh developers "missing" the entire server side component. Calling them escapers, or encoders would probably be more appropriate since sanitization implies safety. I wouldn't count on Angular.js to even encode data that could be malicious. For server side validated HTML though, I do see the benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Pagedown can run on the server as well as the client.

For sanitizing html on the client, it makes more sense to sanitize on output rather than input. You wouldn't sanitize before *sending* data to a server, but you might sanitize after *recieving* data from a server.

Imagine making a web-service call on the client and obtaining data from a third-party service. It could be passed through a sanitizer on the client before being rendered. The user could disable the sanitization on their own computer, but they're only hurting themselves.

It's also useful outside of security reasons just to prevent user input accidentally modifying the formatting of the surrounding page. Such as when typing a html post with a real-time preview (like on StackOverflow).

Answer (score -2):

**Not at all safe.**

Client side sanitation/validation should be used for few reasons:

- easier and faster way to tell the non-malicious user what he did wrong
- decrease the number of times non-malicious user communicate with your server (in case of errors)

Everything that you validate can be changed because the client is not controlled by you. Things like dev console, [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), wireshark allows you to manipulate the data in basically any way you want.

**So only server is responsible for real sanitation/validation.**

Comment: This question is **not** about validation; it's about sanitization.

Comment: @ExpertSystem Can you please explain how is is different in this content? Validating - telling whether the data is in correct format (yes/no). Sanitation - making a data which is not in correct format to be in correct format. So the question to both - NO is can not be safe, because both things can be tampered. If the only problem is just not having the word sanitation in my text - it is easily fixable.

Comment: No, it is not a matter of "wording". It's a totally different concept that hapens at totally different places/points in time. Have you read my answer ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem yes, I read it. Also it is much longer than my, but the answer is similar - it is not safe, it is only for convenience and better user experience. His question - "is it safe", so basically can I rely on this sanitizer and assume it is bullet proof. My answer is - no you can not and never should. It can be tampered. Do not see where I am wrong. Yes, I have not explained how sanitizer works in angular, but I do not need to do this

Comment: I don't think you understand what a sanitizer is for. The reasons you mention as applying to both sanitization and validation do **not** apply to the former. Of course, it doesn't make your app bullet-proof (nothing can do that), but it does meke it a lot safer (in several ways).