# iframe not working in AngularJS 1.3.0

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I'm new to web dev. I'm using AngularJS 1.3.0. When I try using {{ things[0].embed }} to insert the embedded source video link from my database, nothing is displayed, but hardcoding the link, for example "//www.youtube.com/embed/wZZ7oFKsKzY", works. Is there something that I'm missing? Am I misusing the scope somehow?
Here's another example of what I'm trying to do. If you replace the {{thing[0].embed}} with the youtube link, it works. Why doesn't it replace the {{thing[0].embed}} with the link?
http://plnkr.co/edit/Udml7NIyWcUuMtYGDXNc?p=preview

```
//myCore.js

var coreControl = angular.module('myCore', []);

function mainController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};

    $http.get('*')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.things = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });

    $scope.doThings = function() {
        $http.post('*', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.formData = {};
                $scope.things   = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
}
```

```
//index.html  
<div ng-if="moves.length==1" class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <h1> {{ things[0].name }} </h1>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src="{{ things[0].embed }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        {{ things[0].embed }}
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot write html directly to a view without sanitizing it first. Check this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs

Comment: Why does hardcoding the link work then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K2fM9Mom4Sqm8LagdERQ?p=preview)

You must explicitly direct angular to trust content that could otherwise provide security holes for xss attacks. That is what the

`$sce.trustResourceAsUrl()`

function call is for.

Comment: A little correction: `ngSrc` is **not** meant for `<img>` elements only. It is meant for **any** element that has a `src` attribute.

Comment: Currently my control.js looks like the following:
http://plnkr.co/edit/gLNzn1MxFRtGGzCIG7Ge?p=catalogue
Does it matter if I have my function as a callback or not? When I tried making my function the second parameter, it didn't work.

Comment: I dont know what callback you are talking about. Are you talking about the promises?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what a promise is. I'm referring to the function that is in the parameter of controller("ctrl", function....) in your plunker example. Could you take a look at the plunker code I posted above you comment? I'm not sure why my $sce.trustAsResourceUrl code doesn't work here.

Comment: Never mind. I'm really new to this web dev stuff and AngularJS. I just got it to work. I was toying around with my code and added another controller function to do the $sce for my embedded link and then set that function as the ng-controller for the div I wanted. Thanks for all the help! :D

Comment: "Plunk not found" - just me or this this link dead?

Answer (score 2):

I know I joined the party late (again), but there you go:

**[Strict Conceptual Escaping (SCE)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)** is an important concept in Angular should not be taken light-heartedly (if you care about the security of your app).

It is important to understand wht it means and what are the implications and dangers in calling `$sce.trustAs...()`.

**[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302909/how-is-concatenating-urls-in-templates-in-angular-less-secure-than-in-other-loca#answer-23740248)** gives a little insight on what is SCE and why does Angular treat resources (such as URLs) the way it does.
**[That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839173/how-safe-is-client-side-html-sanitization#answer-23839691)** explains the importance of client-side sanitization (this is what you by-pass by calling `$sce.trustAs...()` unless you are 100% sure that you can trust it).

---

That said, there might be better (read "safer and more maintainable") ways to achieve the same result.

E.g. **[`$sceDelegateProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider)** (which is used by the `$sce` service to decide what is secure and what isn't) provides methods to **[white-list](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider#resourceUrlWhitelist)**/**[black-list](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider#resourceUrlBlacklist)** resources using string-matching (with optional wildcards) or regular expressions (not recommended).
For more info on how to populate your white-/black-list take a look **[here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#format-of-items-in-link-ng-scedelegateprovider-resourceurlwhitelist-resourceurlwhitelist-link-ng-scedelegateprovider-resourceurlblacklist-blacklist-a-name-resourceurlpatternitem-a-)**.

---

E.g. if you want your application to allow links from `www.youtube.com`, you can define your white-list like this:

```
.config(function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',   // trust all resources from the same origin
        '*://www.youtube.com/**'   // trust all resources from `www.youtube.com`
    ]);
});
```

See, also, this **[updated demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gtToyPL5QRJwyjYoE6uJ?p=preview)**.