# Returning functional HTML code through Angular JS filter

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-filters

I'm trying to filter any text through angular to return a font-awesome icon. Instead It's just returning plain text. Anyone know a fix? Thanks!

```
.filter('textToIcon', function($sce) {
return function(text) {
    if(text!==''){
        return '<i class="fa fa-child"></i>';
    }
}
```

Comment: See similar question [here][1]. There is a working pluker demo as well. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284965/angular-filter-return-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is "Strict Conceptual Escaping" (SCE) in action.
For more information on what it is and how it works, take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839173/how-safe-is-client-side-html-sanitization#answer-23839691)**.

In a few words, Angular tries to protect your users from untrusted content that could do bad things to them. If you know that the values are safe to be interpreted as HTML, there are two approaches you can take:

1. Import `ngSanitize` (it is available as a separate module) and add it as a dependency in your module (e.g. `angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])`). You are set (as long as you pass safe values to `ngBindHtml`) !
2. Use `$sce` to specify that certain stuff is explicitly trusted (by you) to be used as HTML:

   .filter('textToIcon', function ($sce) {
       return function (text) {
           if (text) {
               return $sce.trustAsHtml('');
           }
       };
   })

---

The former approach is strongly recommended !